# how can i avoid writing multiple replace() for this below code for a string

Tags: java, string, replace

Current String => String str = abcd.d.904100:18.xyz  to String str= 7.125.904100.18
Here i need to replace 1- abcd.d to 7.125  2- replace : with . 3- replace .xyz to empty . The below is what i have tried

`

```
String str = abcd.d.904100:18.xyz;
  String str1= str.replace("abcd.d", "7.125");
  String str2= str1.replace(":", ".");
  String str3= str2.replace(".xyz","");//or
  String str1 = str.replace("abcd.d","7.125").replace(":",".").replace(".xyz","");
```

`

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The last line is perfectly fine both in what it does, as well as readability.

Comment: i was checking to see if there is any possblity to avoid 3 replace